# Using a array instead of appending to string

Tags: php, arrays, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String concatenation vs array implode in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847356/string-concatenation-vs-array-implode-in-php)

there are situations in which you build the string trough a function like:

```
$output = '';

if($something) $output .= '<div>foo</div>';
if($something_else) $output .= '<div>moo</div>';

...


echo $output;
```

Do you think it's better to use a array instead and implode it at the end?

```
$output = array();

if($something) $output[] = '<div>foo</div>';
if($something_else) $output[] = '<div>moo</div>';

...


echo implode("\n", $output);
```

Is it considered a better practice?

Comment: i think appending string is better, but then again its just my personal preference.

Comment: In it's current form, this question is quite subjective.

Comment: i wouldn't use the implode method as you may as well use the var concat, but there is noting wrong with using an array when its named like $output['page'] and concat that.

Comment: @esqew - I disagree. As with everything code related, proper benchmarking will reveal which is faster.

Comment: @kev - I see where you're coming from there, but the question "Is it... a better practice?" is really dependent on who you're asking. He didn't really specify a standpoint (i.e. memory usage/efficiency, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably take a performance hit using arrays.
It most cases it would be small enough not to cause a problem.

But it's hard to say because you provide no context whatsoever.